# How to get the depth (number of levels) of an XML Branch in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, depth, levels

For example, if I have an XML like:

```
<country>
  <state name="a">
    <city>
      <neigbor name="n" />
    </city>
  </state>
  <state name="b">
  </state>
</country>
```

The branch country has the max deep of 3. Because you can go thru the deepest node: 
country(0)  -->  state(1)  -->  city(2)  --> neigbor(3)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any built-in way to get max depth of xml, but your algorithm can be refined:

```
public function getXmlDepth(x:XML):int{
    var res:int = 0;                
    for each(var node:XML in x.children()){
        res=Math.max(res,getXmlDepth(node)+1);
    }
    return res;         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Friends!!! I wrote next code using recursive algorithms to reach this goal

```
        public function getMaxDeep() : int {
            var deep : int = getMaxDeepRecursive(dataProvider,0);
            return deep;
        }

        public function getMaxDeepRecursive(element:XML, deep : int) : int {
            if(element.children().length()==0) return deep;
            var maxDeep : int = 0;
            for each(var item : XML in element.children()) {
                var element : XML = item;
                var otherDeep : int = getMaxDeepRecursive(element,deep+1);
                if(otherDeep>maxDeep) maxDeep = otherDeep;
            }
            if(deep>maxDeep) maxDeep = deep;
            return maxDeep;             
        }
```

But I want to know if there's another approach ;)